# Assigning multiple values to std::array in std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, stl

When using std::array I can assign values at one time:

```
std::array<int, 3> a2 = {1, 2, 3};
```

But I don't know the best way to do it when the above array is combined into a map:

```
using namespace std;
map <string, array<int, 3>> myMap;

//I'm doing it like below now...

array<int, 3> tempArray = {1,2,3}; // can I save this line somehow?
myMap[myString] = tempArray;
```

Please also let me know if this is actually the right way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While using `insert` as shown in the other answer is more efficient, you can also use

```
myMap["foo"] = {{1,2,3}};
```

if concise code is more important to you.

Comment: @ShmilTheCat The question is about C++11 and doesn't indicate the need for a specific compiler. It works with GCC 4.6.3, GCC 4.7.2, GCC 4.8.0 and Clang 3.2. It's standard-conforming C++11.

Answer (score 2):

You can save a line (though not many characters) like this:

```
myMap.insert(std::make_pair(myString,array<int,3>{{1,2,3}}));
```

BTW, according to GCC 4.7.2 you are missing a pair of braces around the initializer for `tempArray`

However this will not modify the mapped value for `myString` if it happens already to exist.

And if and when you have a library that has [std::map::emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) you can save more characters.

Comment: I believe it should compile as c+11, as tagged. It compiles under gcc 4.7.2, clang-3.2 and intel c++ 2013.2

Comment: The extent of c++11 support in MSVC++ 2012 is shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx. It does not support initializer lists, among much else.

Comment: @ShmilTheCat And [here's](http://cpprocks.com/c11-compiler-support-shootout-visual-studio-gcc-clang-intel/) a good comparison chart for C++11 feature support in VC 2012 Nov CTP, GCC 4.8, Clang 3.3 and Intel 13 compiler. That said: Have you installed and enabled CTP?

Comment: @DanielFrey msvc++ 2012 novemer ctp does support initializer lists in user code but the special constructors / inserters for standard containers haven't been implemented yet, but will be in the rtm version.